# Where do I put the spotify apiKey in this endpoint link in gson in java?

Tags: java, gson, spotify

### Some starting information, I am using the gson library and the httpRequest and httpResponse java libraries to get the information out of the json output from the Spotify RESTful api.

I was curious to where I would put the apiKey (more specifically, the "token") in the httpRequest link? The api documentation that spotify provides gives this link to find a specific album based on the id given:
[https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/{id}](https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/%7Bid%7D)
but everywhere in the documentation shows a completely different way to put the apiKey in than I am used to for gson (just putting it in the link like key=378991890382098209).
Does anyone know that has used the spotify api know where I put it for gson?

I don't know what to try, but I have been looking through the api documentation.